# android real time multiplayer game - share data between players before the game starts

Tags: android, google-play-services, real-time, google-play-games, multiplayer

i am programming a real time multiplayer quiz game in android ([google developers](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer)). I started with the code of googles Button Clicker 2000. My quiz game is running but i have some problems. All players should start at the same time. In the method

`@Override
public void onRoomConnected(int statusCode, Room room) {`

i am defining a host (1 player). The host creates quiz-questions. After creation he sends the questions to everybody. Now the onRoomConnected method is finished and the gamephase starts. But sometimes other players didn't received their questions early enough and i get a nullpointer exception.
Is there a way to start the game after all players received the questions?

Thanks in advance!

Update:

Ray Wenderlichs Real Time Multiplayer Tutorial was very helpful. A interesting chapter is "Synchronizing Game Start". Unfortunately it is not exactly what i am searching.
[Tutorial Real Time Multiplayer](http://www.raywenderlich.com/89724/creating-cross-platform-multiplayer-game-unity-part-4)

Comment: When you're getting NPE, is the `statusCode` not `STATUS_OK`? Its suggested that you have to handle errors in `onRoomConnected` if such a case occurs. The API classes handle the calls so we can't really set a delay timer once `onRoomConnected` has been called (it will still have the NPE error even if you implement one, if I understood it correctly).

Comment: I always get STATUS_OK Code. The NPE occurs later during my gamelogic phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OnRoomConnected(), it is best if you decide the host is, say Participant[0]from GetParticipants(), and then use SendMessage to send the required data to the remaining players and parse it in OnRealtimeMessageReceived(). And then start the game once everyone has received the data.

Comment: I already have implement this steps. My Question is: When do i know that everyone received the data?

Comment: How about sending a GotData message back to the host? Once he gets that message from all clients, broadcast a START GAME event.